# Are Skylanders swap force figures console specific?

Tags: skylanders-swap-force

Can I use any figure on an XBox and then take it and use it on Wii?

Comment: I'm going to take a guess here based on the Skylanders character packaging and say yes. Typically, if something will only work on one or the other, it will say on the front of the package pretty clearly so people don't buy the wrong one for their console/system.

Answer (score 2):

After doing a bit of looking, I believe I can say that yes, they can be used cross-console.

I did some looking, and as noted in my comment, a video game accessory will usually indicate its console, from my experiences, to help users. I have not seen this on any Swap Force characters.

Additionally, Amazon has them listed on multiple platforms, as have a few other shopping sites I've checked. Right below the item, it will say "Platform:" and list all platforms it works on. All platforms for the Skylanders series are listed, therefore I believe that they work cross-console.

Comment: I'm glad I could find an answer quickly for you. I hope it helps.